# Rancher services DNS resolution issue

Tags: dns, rancher

I am looking for ways to make my Rancher services available to the outside world.

#### Environment

- local ESXi env. with

  - 1x Software FW
  - 1x CentOS as Rancher manager
  - 3x CentOS as Rancher hosts
- Rancher Cattle env. with those 3 hosts
- Public DNS resolved, `*.mydomain.com` terminates at the Rancher admin console

#### Issue

Resolving DNS: while I do understand the internal scheme of `servicename.stackname`, I don't quite understand how I can make these services available with a public DNS. What I know already is that I will need a load balancer on all of the stacks that I want to make available.

#### Requirement

What I would need is something like fqdn `servicename.stackname.mydomain.com` be made available from the outside. So basically I presume I would need a local DNS that I can make available to the outside world. I then figure that when a DNS query is looking for `servicename.stackname.mydomain.com`, the public DNS will delegate the query to the DNS in my environment.
Will this work and if so, could someone point me in the right direction on how to implement s.th. like this? I can't seem to be able to find good instructions on the web on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the info I had from the admin of the zone in question had been incorrect – the wildcard A-record had not been in place...

After he had it added, everything worked fine...